# jQuery UI, HTML in autocomplete

Tags: html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to do the exact same thing as in:
http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/html.html

But it's not working, label AND value are showed in the autocomplete, ie when i'm inputting "a": "aardvark", "< b>apple" and "< i>atom" are displayed in the box below my input.

My HTML is:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="recherche" />
</form>
```

My jQuery is:

```
      $('#recherche').autocomplete({
        source: [
            {
                label: "aardvark", 
                value: "aardvark"
            },
            {
                label: "<b>apple</b>",
                value: "apple"
            },
            {
                label: "<i>atom</i>",
                value: "atom"
            }
        ],
        html: true
    });
```

And I'm using jQuery UI 1.11.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've missed **jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js** as the *source* you've give in your question has used it.

Here I've created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/rpaw5eeo/1)

Markup:

```
<form>
    <input id="recherche" />
</form>
```

JavaScript code:

```
(function( $ ) {

var proto = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype,
    initSource = proto._initSource;

function filter( array, term ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
    return $.grep( array, function(value) {
        return matcher.test( $( "<div>" ).html( value.label || value.value || value ).text() );
    });
}

$.extend( proto, {
    _initSource: function() {
        if ( this.options.html && $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                response( filter( this.options.source, request.term ) );
            };
        } else {
            initSource.call( this );
        }
    },

    _renderItem: function( ul, item) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a></a>" )[ this.options.html ? "html" : "text" ]( item.label ) )
            .appendTo( ul );
    }
});

})( jQuery );

$('#recherche').autocomplete({
        source: [
            {
                label: "aardvark", 
                value: "aardvark"
            },
            {
                label: "<b>apple</b>",
                value: "apple"
            },
            {
                label: "<i>atom</i>",
                value: "atom"
            }
        ],
        html: true
    });
```

using that *jquery.ui.autocomplete* js and its working perfectly fine.

Please do have a look, it will do the trick for you.